# Rewrite subdirectory url to file

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a subdirectory called test, http://www.mywebsite.com/test/.  Inside of the directory is an index.php file.

I want to put an .htaccess file inside of the test subdirectory that will rewrite the URLs so that http://www.mywesbite.com/test/paul will become http://www.mywebsite.com/test?author=paul, and so that urls like http://www.mywebsite.ocom/test/sam/3 will become http://www.mywebsite.com/test?author=sam&test=3

This is what I have so far:

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymlinks

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (/test/)
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/?$ /test/index.php?author=$1&page=$2 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (/test/)
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/?$ /test/index.php?author=$1 [L]
```

Unfortunately, I get a 404 Not Found error.  Am I missing something?  Any thoughts are much appreciated!

**EDIT**:  I checked phpinfo() and mod_rewrite does seem to be showing as a loaded module.

This is what my virtual host file looks like too.  It looks like AllowOverride is set as well.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mywebsite.com
    ServerAlias www.mywebsite.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/mywebsite.com/httpdocs
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/mywebsite.com-error_log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/mywebsite.com-access_log combined
    HostnameLookups Off
    UseCanonicalName Off
    ServerSignature On
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/var/www/html/mywebsite.com/httpdocs/"

    <Directory "/var/www/html/mywebsite.com/httpdocs/">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    <IfModule mod_userdir.c>
        UserDir public_html
        Include /etc/apache2/mod_userdir.conf
    </IfModule>
</VirtualHost>
```

**EDIT 2**: I also wanted to mention, I put some junk text in the .htaccess file to try and break it, and instead of a 404 error I got an internal server error, so it does seem like the .htaccess file is being read.

Comment: Your examples imply a rewrite to /test?author=.... But your code is showing a rewrite to /test/index.php?author=.. Can you clarify which one you're trying to do?

Answer (score 3):

I tested Panama Jack's solution and it seems like the RewriteRules are not accounting for this already being in /test/.htaccess... so this would not work for the first example (/test/paul). Proposing an alternate solution that should work for both examples:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /test/
RewriteRule ^(.+)/(.+)/?$ index.php?author=$1&page=$2 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index\.php$
RewriteRule ^(.+)/?$ index.php?author=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thank you again for answering, unfortunately though it's still not working, and the error log is still strangely saying that the file /home/vhosts/piperforum.com/httpdocs/test/paul doesn't exist.  This does seem strange, I'm not sure what might be happening in  my system that's causing this, it's a bit odd.

Comment: The VHost config you posted shows the DocumentRoot as `/var/www/html/mywebsite.com/httpdocs/` but your error is citing a completely different path `/home/vhosts/piperforum.com/httpdocs/` so looks like the request is being handled by a different site.

Comment: My apologies, I'm also testing on different sample vhosts at the moment to verify the issue, when I checked the mywebsite.com vhost it was still showing that same error, the file /home/var/www/html/mywebsite.com/httpdocs/test/paul doesn't exist.

Comment: Is your Rewrite module enabled in the main config? `LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so`

Comment: Hi again, I do have that line showing in my httpd.conf, it also shows as loaded in phpinfo().

Comment: It sounds like your rewrites just aren't being executed. What if you just do something simple like `RewriteEngine On` and `RewriteRule .* - [F]` in your /test/.htaccess or even your root /.htaccess.

Comment: Surprisingly, nothing happens, either in the root or in the test folder.  It seems the rewrite module isn't working at all, which is strange since it's showing in php_info().  I know the htaccess file is itself working as well, since putting junk text inside causes a 500 internal server error.  Is there a reason that mod_rewrite might not be working?  It's strange.

Comment: @ZeroWing I've exhausted the possible causes I know of given my experience with the **standard Apache distrib**. If you haven't already, you should follow the steps for enabling Rewrite for **your specific distrib** (I assume you are using Ubuntu?). e.g. `sudo a2enmod rewrite` and Allowoverride All for default site and/or conf..etc. You can find plenty of web docs and other stackoverflow Posts devoted to this. If all else fails, best to post a new question for help with getting Rewrite mod working. Once you do, then come back to this Post to test the RewriteRules themselves. Hope that helps.

Comment: [Setting up Rewrite for Apache-Ubuntu](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-mod_rewrite-for-apache-on-ubuntu-14-04)